# Fresh Kdenlive Install Error

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, kdenlive

My hard drive is wearing out.  I've decided to do a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 install.  I've now come to installing Kdenlive.

I've installed Kdenlive and the Kden runtime environment.  I am getting the following error when I go to load it.  I don't know enough about this if they are all part of the same or if there is more than 1 issue.

```
rpiggott@rpiggott-Aspire-5742Z:~$ kdenlive
Invalid Context= "stock" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/stock/16/"
Invalid Context= "stock" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/stock/22/"
Invalid Context= "stock" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/stock/24/"
Invalid Context= "stock" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/stock/32/"
Invalid Context= "stock" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/stock/48/"
Invalid Context= "stock" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/stock/64/"
Invalid Context= "stock" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/stock/128/"
qrc:/qml/kdenliveclipmonitor.qml:1:1: module "QtQuick.Controls" is not installed
qrc:/qml/kdenliveclipmonitor.qml:2:1: module "QtQuick.Controls.Styles" is not installed
qrc:/qml/kdenliveclipmonitor.qml:1:1: module "QtQuick.Controls" is not installed
qrc:/qml/kdenliveclipmonitor.qml:2:1: module "QtQuick.Controls.Styles" is not installed
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Please file a bug report [on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kdenlive) or subscribe to [an existing similar bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kdenlive/+bug/1464028).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some problem with kdenlive package itself, and the bug was reported.

Issue: The meta-package "kdenlive" does not contain all the required dependencies to run Kdenlive in Ubuntu 16.10

They have omitted a package(qml-module-qtquick-controls) in it. There is a very simple workaround for it. Just install the package(dependency) they have missed by using the following:

> sudo apt-get install qml-module-qtquick-controls

[Link for the detailed bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kdenlive/+bug/1641192)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I installed "qml-module-qtquick-controls" and it worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)